# Brick Rigs Graphics Issue

Tags: technical-issues, linux, wine, dxvk, brick-rigs

So I am currently trying to run Brick Rigs on my Linux Machine using Wine and DXVK. Game runs and I can "play" but the key is I can't see anything, that means I only see one color instead of the game.
Screenshot:
[image: Brick Rigs]

It happens no matter I'm in game or Main Menu.


Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i3-3217U
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000
- RAM: 8GB
- Display: 1366x768 60Hz

Comment: Can you try playing it on Steam with the Proton Compatibility layer?